# Как запустить установку ubuntu из запущенной другой ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как установить ubuntu из другой рабочей ubuntu. Если нет флешки или dvd диска?
Скачал ISO образ, а дальше что делать?

Comment: Почитать тут, должно подойти - https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_ubuntu_%D1%81_iso

Comment: если в двух словах, то: разбиваешь/форматируешь диски, устанавливаешь в новый корень с помощью [`debootstrap`](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Debootstrap) базовую систему, `chroot`'ишься туда, устанавливаешь то что нужно, устанавливаешь загрузчик... аналогично можно сделать из под любой linux-системы, где доступен интернет и debootstrap... dvd при этом не нужен, но для этого всего надо обладать определёнными познаниями...